# Convert/Get a Zone from its linked zone?

Tags: javascript, moment-timezone

I'm using `ng2-timezone-selector` library and it depends on `moment-timezone`. Looking into the source code of both, I've learned that:
 1. `ng2-timezone-selector` keeps a hardcoded list of timezones in its source code.
 2. `moment-timezone` has a `links` and `names` list as well.

Given my current location, my timezone from `moment.tz.guess()` is `Asia/Saigon`. In `moment-timezone` library, it's not being listed in the `names` list but it's found in `links` list as `Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh | Asia/Saigon`. Now, in `ng2-timezone-selector`, `Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh` is being used in its hardcoded timezones list.

Is there a way for me to grab `Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh` from `Asia/Saigon`? Any suggestions at all?

Thanks